# Variable global scope

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to create a few custom post types, and instead of hard-coding their names I just want to define them as a globally scoped variable.
I thought I understood the scope but apparently not. The code below results in an error of  `Undefined variable`:

```
$filmLabel = "Films";
$showLabel = "Shows";
function CreatePostTypes() {
    register_post_type( $filmLabel, GenerateFilmType($filmLabel));
    register_post_type( $showLabel, GenerateFilmType($showLabel));
}
add_action( 'init', 'CreatePostTypes' );
```

I've tried using `$GLOBAL` as well, with the same result.
Can anyone spot what's wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Using global vars is generally bad practice. The accepted answer on [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89263/how-to-set-and-use-global-variables-or-why-not-to-use-them-at-all) gives a good explanation why.

Comment: @vancoder 
Generally I'm sure it is bad practice. Randomly hard-coding magic values everywhere is worse practice, I'm sure. That's why.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687363/access-a-global-variable-in-a-php-function

Comment: So the actual real reason why using globals is a bad idea is because of syntactically useless it is to do so. Cheers

Comment: @Fluxian "Randomly hard-coding magic values" - a post type name/slug is not random. And it shouldn't change, otherwise all your data gets lost. Instead of the `define()` which seems a bit dated in modern PHP, I would simply go with a public class constant.

Comment: @kero Well that's a whole conversation about what is considered random I guess. But something that is "repeated often and heavily subject to change" is perhaps a more concise formulation. What's dated about define(), and how would you address a site-wide constant with a public class constant?

Comment: @Fluxian "heavily subject to change" - the post type slug **should never change**. In my setups I usually have the namespace `\Vendor\Project\PostTypes` and in there e.g. `\Vendor\Project\PostTypes\Film` and `\Vendor\Project\PostTypes\Film::SLUG` would be the slug that is referenced everywhere I need it.

Comment: @kero Post types in live production sites should never change, sure. But finding the best taxonomy while under development will be subject to change. I'm struggling to figure out what you're actually referencing and what you put in those files you mentioned?

Comment: @Fluxian I can't add an answer now, first because I don't have much time and second because the question is closed. My plugins always use object oriented code (oop). So each post type will have a class that represents it (that is what `\Vendor\Project\PostTypes\Film` is meant to represent - a class within a namespace). The class will have methods, one of which e.g. calls `register_post_type` while other methods might create ACF for it. Within that class is a public const with all relevant "magic strings", so they're only defined once, in other places I use the reference to that const

Comment: @kero I suppose that's a fine way of doing it too, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globals are generally discourgaged. You can use [define](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) instead.

```
<?php
define("FILM_LABEL", "Films");
define("SHOW_LABEL", "Shows");
function CreatePostTypes() {
    register_post_type( FILM_LABEL, GenerateFilmType( FILM_LABEL ) );
    register_post_type( SHOW_LABEL, GenerateFilmType( SHOW_LABEL ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'CreatePostTypes' );
```

Comment: Ah right. That's exactly what I was trying to do. Awesome!

Comment: No problem, it's especially useful for storing app-keys, passwords and the like in wp-config.php ( assuming the wp-config.php is not publicly visible on github as that would defeat the purpose )